# How to unlock iPhone 5 (iOS 7.0.2) after forgetting my Apple ID?

Tags: ios

I have an iPhone 5 (iOS 7.0.2) which is locked and I can't unlock it because I've forgotten my Apple ID.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please don't use all caps (it won't help get an answer quicker) and the site works best when there's one question per question - if you have another question ask it separately. Also, tags are supposed to relate to the question, so the [tag:osx] tag is for OS X questions, not iOS questions.

Comment: The only way to unlock the device is to reset your Apple ID (see the answer by @grgarside). Apple implemented this feature to curb theft and it works. If you are in unlawful possession of someone else's device, then you effectively have a brick on your hands. There is absolutely no way to bypass the lock without the pass or to reset it outside of the proper channel. You can read more about the feature here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5818?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US (Note the section entitled: "What if I forget my Apple ID password?")

Answer (score 3):

It is currently not possible to bypass Activation Lock, since the activation lock data is stored remotely on Apple's servers.

You can attempt to recover your Apple ID by following the instructions at [iforgot.apple.com](https://iforgot.apple.com/).

---

You can read more about Activation Lock (and whether it can be bypassed) here:

- [How secure is Activation Lock on iOS 7 (and later)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104888/activation-lock-on-ios-7-how-secure-is-it)