# How to unlock an iPhone 5C?

Tags: unlock, iphone

My brother-in-law works at a bar. He has had an iPhone 5C there for months, so he took it and tried to find the owner's phone number so he could contact them about their phone, but iCloud didn't let him get far.

Months went by without anyone coming back to claim it. Now he has given it to me. I have tried my hardest to find at least a number to call but nothing.

Any suggestions how to get the phone unlocked or extract the owner's phone number?

Comment: Turn it in to local law enforcement, they have the ability to get owners info from apple.  The apple store can NOT help, if you can identify the carrier their store may or may not collect the phone and contact the owner.  I've recently been thru attempting to locate an owner of a lost iPhone.

Comment: Neither Apple nor the carrier can say with *absolute* certainty that the person they have on record is actually the current owner.

Comment: Have you checked if they set up a Medical ID? From the lock screen, swipe or click the home button to open the passcode screen, click emergency then Medical ID. If they have this set up you will be able to access their emergency contacts as well as make the call from that phone if the sim is still usable etc.

Answer (score 2):

Though this is in effect a duplicate of [How can I bypass Activation Lock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock) as it's a nice clean question, looking for a legitimate solution - to which only the police or perhaps network provider might be able to assist.

It does, however give an opportunity for a lesson in "be prepared".

In this circumstance, or indeed if you were in an accident - if the authorities can't get in your phone they may not even know who you are..

Solution - 5 minutes in Photoshop or Gimp…

**Put your ICE on your lock screen.**

[image]

The picture needs to be 200px larger than your screen resolution in both directions, because of the parallax/motion effect, & it might need a couple of attempts to get the text out of the way of the Slide to Unlock, but it's well worth it for peace of mind.

Comment: Good advice. Does not address the OP's question, however.

Comment: The question is well-answered in the original, I didn't feel the need to go over it again.

Comment: Perhaps, but on SE, it's generally frowned upon (for good reason), to simply post links. Instead, it's better to summarise the important bits in an answer so the solution is not lost once the source goes offline or such.

Comment: Let a mod decide. Flag it if you don't like it.