# How can I wipe my iPhone to start over with Find My iPhone active?

Tags: ios, iphone, find-my-iphone

I want to get rid of an old email Apple ID on my iPhone 5s. At this point I just want to wipe the entire phone clean and start over. How can I do that if I can’t turn off “Find My iPhone”?

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done with Find My iPhone active. You need to disable Find My iPhone before you can erase/restore the device.

If you restore the device in restore mode, then you will enter Activation Lock. This cannot be 'bypassed'—you will have to have it disabled by Apple if you can not enter the Apple ID credentials. For more information on Activation Lock, see:

- [How can I bypass Activation Lock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock)

Answer (score 0):

Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content & Settings

Comment: You can't do this with Find My iPhone active.