# 7.0.4 iCloud password forgot

Tags: iphone

I have a phone that has a friends iCloud account on and they don't know the password for it. How do I get rid of the account.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I bypass Activation Lock?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock)

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplicate to me, the previous owner is known to the asker here (as compared to the linked question).

Answer (score 1):

Ask your friend to recover the password via https://iforgot.apple.com/ and then to follow the steps documented in [What to do before selling or giving away your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351).