# How to remove iCloud account from used iPhone?

Tags: icloud

I bought an iPhone 4s used and the previous owner did not clear their iCloud account. I need to reset phone, but can't turn off "Find my Phone" because of iCloud password!

How can delete iCloud without a password?

Answer (score 0):

Take it back to the shop. Only the original owner can disable it, or Apple, if you can prove ownership & sale by its original owner [which is harder than you think].

See [How can I bypass Activation Lock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock/120695#120695)

If you can contact the original owner, then point them to this Apple web page -
[What to do before selling or giving away your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-is/HT201351)

…see about halfway down, how they can do it after they already sold the phone.
Once they have removed it from their iCloud account, it will unlock & you can set up as a new device.

Comment: Thanks I bought it from a individual. They seem to be willing to work with me for now! I'm just impatient and want it resolved so I can get it activated for my husband.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link they should see