# I brought an iPhone but now think it's stolen, what can I do?

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud

I bought an iPhone off a lady which by now I thank was a stolen phone:

- I tried to activate the phone I got right through to wifi settings
- Now I'm stuck on iCloud settings and asked for pervious Apple ID

There is a number displayed to call in case the phone is found, but that number is not active.

What can I do now?

Comment: @Patrix, rather then deleting my well meant comments all over the place, how about doing some real work and taking care of this with -6 votes ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 This site is community-moderated. Any user who sees a way to improve a question can do so by editing it him/herself, this does not require moderator privileges at all (handling flags on comments does though)

Answer (score 3):

You can't do anything. It wouldn't be a very good deterrent against theft if you could [bypass the activation lock](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/).

Don't buy stolen goods in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Ring the phone number, let the original owner know you 'found' it.
If the number doesn't work, hand it in to the police.

There is no way to [bypass the activation lock](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/).

Consider the £250 a lesson learned.

Comment: If the owner answers ask for finders fee....  $250 :)

Comment: That did strike me as a possibility ;)