# Forgotten iCloud email ID and password

Tags: ios, icloud, apple-id, activation-lock

I am the owner of an iPhone 4s. One day I tried to put my SIM card into my iPhone and the next thing I saw on my phone was "Activation Required".

Unfortunately, I have forgotten my iCloud Apple ID and Password. I tried to find it with iForgot but it is not finding my name. I created the iCloud email. How can I find it and regain access to my iCloud account?

Comment: Not finding your name ? what is wrong with that ?

Comment: If you can't find it through iforgot, then the only other way would be to take it to Apple with proof of ownership.

Comment: Is the phone deactivated - as in unusable? Or does it ask for activation for something like iMessage or Facetime?

Comment: you need the apple id which was previously used to use your iPhone. If you can't remember, it can't be used.

Answer (score 3):

Most people start at https://iforgot.apple.com and work through apple support. Same as if you forgot your bank password or email - you go through the support organization and get your account returned to you. You would need to do that or go though support to reset the Activation lock presuming you can prove you're the original purchaser of the equipment.

See:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201441
- [How can I bypass Activation Lock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock)