# Iphone 5s: Can not find apple id

Tags: iphone, apple-id

I was wondering whether there is a way to find the appleid of an iphone that is stuck in the activation screen, when connecting it to itunes on a computer that was connected in the past.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I bypass Activation Lock?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock)

Answer (score 1):

If you take it to the Apple Store or call AppleCare they'll be able to look this up for you, from your device's serial number.