# iPhone Apple ID compromised

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id, cellular-carriers

my ex gave me his old iPhone and set up the cloud thing for me. He has changed the password so I can't download apps or anything. Also he got me a good deal with Talktalk. The contract is his but I'm paying for it they my bank. Problem is Talktalk will only talk to him and any correspondence goes to him. How can I get out of this situation and control my own stuff?

Comment: Talk to Apple re the iPhone - similar to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock - different reason, same answers. With TalkTalk, I suspect you're stuck. At worst cancel the payment, they'll go to him for the arrears, not you. Set up a new provider.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Normally I discourage multiple questions per question, but this is amenable to a great answer fleshing out what @Tetsujin said. To regain control, deal with the following in order: a) recover your iCloud password or abandon that account b) recover activation control of the iPhone or abandon that device c) recover control of the phone number or abandon it