# Delete an old icloud account with defunct email and forgotten password

Tags: icloud, apple-id

I have an old email/id apple iCloud account on an iPad mini that I can't delete because the email is totally defunct and I cannot remember the password.

I have a newer iCloud account that I use for everything and have no problem with it, except that I cannot use it on my iPad mini because it keeps asking me for the old account's password. I have read through the boards and am stuck!

So, defunct email and forgotten password and I don't care if I have to reset the entire mini as long as it wipes out the old iCloud account. I haven't used the mini for a while so it doesn't have anything that can't be synced.

HELP- please. Soo frustrating to realize mistakes in hindsight!
Thanks,
Alison

Comment: You've found the anti-theft lock.  If you can't log into to the Apple ID online or change its password then your stuck hard.... See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock

Comment: From where precisely do you wish to delete the defunct account?

Answer (score 2):

Contact [Apple Support](http://www.apple.com/support/contact/). Usually when you create an Apple ID, you supply a credit card #, an address, phone number, etc, all of which can be used to verify your identity. Worth a shot.