# iphone 4s< update and find my iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update

An iphone 4s at iOS 9.0.2 is asking to upgrade to iOS 9.1

The problem is that we know it's activation locked and we don't have control of that Apple ID.

[Since I cant disable it if I can't remember a password](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock). So if i update my iphone this will not block it or leave the phone bricked?

<sup>(The back story if it matters is problem when iphone was buyed from second hand user forget remove his accaunt, all was disabled but i make stupid thing i enable Find my iphone and now i cant nothing to do.)</sup>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I bypass Activation Lock?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock)

Comment: No i want understand update block device or not. and my friend says that function Find my iphone is disables it self when updating is it true. i dont need activate device. it already activated and used as phone.

Comment: There is very little you can do if you don't know the activation account & password.

Comment: To be clear, what version of iOS are you thinking of updating to and what version of iOS is on the device right now.

Comment: iOS 9.0.2 to 9.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you update the phone, you might be prompted to reenter the password that you do not know.

However, if the update goes bad due to file system corruption on the device you will not have the option to erase the device and start over.

For that reason I would recommend not doing anything until you can get control of the device or you have a budget to replace it should you lose control of the secondhand and activation locked phone.

Comment: ОК thanx for advice!

Comment: Having just updated to 9.1 a little less than 5 minutes ago - you are definitely asked for your iCloud account p/w at update... whether or not that is, in fact, the same as the activation account password I cannot say, as for me they are one & the same.