# Tracking of a stolen iphone

Tags: icloud, iphone

My iPhone has been stolen yesterday.
I have put it in lost mode from icloud at same day.

It is showing "**Lost mode is pending**" because it is switched off.

But my iphone is configured with touch ID so user is not able 
to conntect to internet then what are the possibilities to track via icloud.

And any other options to track it ?

Comment: You don't have to unlock the phone to connect to wifi. You can do it by pulling control center from the bottom of the screen. I do not think that your thief would do that, but a chance is still there.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Is this any possibilities to get it back, If thief will go to mobile center and try to
reset iphone or any other activity with iphone.

Comment: Once it will connect to a network you could see it's location via 'find iphone' the next best thing I can suggest you is to to go that location and in find iphone press make noise so that your phone will start a serene so hopefully you can hear it and figure it where it is or who has it. Good luck finding your phone.

Comment: It is not possible as i am in another city now :(

Answer (score -1):

Have you put a passcode on your iPhone? If yes then, the chance for thief to use your iPhone is slim. But if the one who stole your iPhone knows something about getting into the phone system like jail breaking, then there's some possibilities that he can use it.

Comment: I think some form of citation to your last speculation would be useful, otherwise it's merely hearsay. See [How can I bypass Activation Lock?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock)