# iPhone 5 iOS 8.0 - Forgot my apple ID password & cannot restore the password

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id, jailbreak, password

I received my dad's old iPhone 5. He remembers the password, but he cannot remember his Apple ID's password, nor the security question, nor the password for the email linked to this account. I can access the phone, even jailbreak it, but how can I remove or change the password of the Apple ID?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I bypass Activation Lock?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock)

Comment: Nope, I am not trying to bypass the activation lock since my phone is already jailbroken..

Comment: If jailbreaking removed the activation lock, you might have a point.

Comment: @Tetsujin Jailbreaking does not remove the activation lock.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson - that was my point entirely

Comment: Looking at this question again, perhaps the answer was simply https://iforgot.apple.com ???

Comment: @Tetsujin Oh, I see what you meant now. Yes, iForgot should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to reset the password of the Apple ID if you don't know neither the answer to the security question nor the password to the email account linked to the Apple ID.

However, you can easily remove the Apple ID from your iPhone. To do this:

1. Go to Settings > iCloud.
2. At the bottom of the page, tap Delete Account.
3. Tap Delete to confirm.

Comment: This will not change who the phone is activation locked to. It will also require the password to switch it off.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple ID is tied to the device's serial number on Apple's servers. You cannot change it without going through Apple. Something that is [technically possible, but unethical](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock), is bypassing the Activation Lock (only if you're jailbroken, and I'm not going to cite any references), which will make your device think that it's tied to someone else's account (or no account at all), but that still doesn't change it on Apple's side.