# apple id locked

Tags: search

I forgot my apple iPhone 6 iCloud username and password and need help resetting.
I went to a shop for selling my phone then seller took my phone and rested it after that I forgot my apple ID and I couldn't active my phone.what can I do?

Comment: Http://iforgot.apple.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone 5 iOS 8.0 - Forgot my apple ID password & cannot restore the password](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218911/iphone-5-ios-8-0-forgot-my-apple-id-password-cannot-restore-the-password)

Answer (score 1):

[This Macworld page](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-recover-forgotten-icloud-password-3599314/) explains how to reset your iCloud password.

1. Open Safari and enter [appleid.apple.com](https://appleid.apple.com).
2. Click `Reset your Password`.
3. Enter your Apple ID and click `Next`.
4. There are three ways you can confirm your identity to Apple. Although you will most likely only see two: **Email Authentication** and **Answer Security Questions**.
5. It's easiest to start with Email Authentication. Select it and click `Next`.  Apple will then send an email to the backup account it has on file. It doesn't tell you which email account this is (it won't be the same email address as you use to sign in). So you'll have to go check your mail accounts and see if the email has come through.
6. You will get an email from Apple with the message How To Reset Your Apple ID Password. Click the Reset Now link in the email and follow the instructions.
7. Apple normally sends the How to Reset Your Apple ID Password email quickly, but you should give it an hour to come through in case there is a problem. If you haven't received the email by then, it may have been sent to an email address you are no longer using. Click Return To My Apple ID.
8. Click `Reset My Password` and enter your Apple ID again and click `Next`. This time choose Answer Security Questions and click Next.
9. Enter your Birth Date using the Month, Day and Year options.
10. Enter the answers to the two security questions. These vary but are based on information you entered when you set up the account, such as your dream job and the name of the city in which your parents met. Click `Next`.

    11. Fill out the New Password and Confirm Password fields. You should use the same password in each field.
    12. Click `Reset password`.