# Forgot passcode. Can't reset without turning off "Find My iPhone". iCloud.com doesn't display phone

Tags: iphone, password, unlock

I forgot the passcode for my old iPhone 4 which I planned on letting my friend borrow while she waits for a new one. Here are the things I tried:

- holding home and sleep/wake button until symbol shows up then holding down those buttons until the reset screen comes up. It seems to work but then still asks for the 4 digit passcode to get into the phone.
- I tried using the restore option on iTunes but because "Find My iPhone" is still activated, it won't let me restore the phone. When I went on iCloud.com to delete it that way, the phone is not on my account for some reason. (I do have a new phone so maybe that one replaced my old phone on iCloud.com?)

Comment: Is erasing the iPhone an option for you?

Comment: Erasing it locally won't gain anything, it will still be activation-locked. The only way out is to call Apple - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock?s=1|1.9441

Comment: @Tetsujin But if I got it right the iPhone isn't activation locked, it's just with iCloud find my iPhone active, it still works, try forcing get it to dfu mode and then restoring with iTunes.

Comment: An iPhone is activation locked the minute the first owner signs it in. Adding it to Find my iPhone enables it to be tracked, removing it again enables it to be sold on, though the ID & p/w is still needed to erase it locally. It being both locked & *not* on Find my iPhone tells me something went wrong somewhere, & Apple are the only people who can investigate that. Otherwise, it's a paperweight.