# iPod email rescue address changed

Tags: ios

My rescue email address changed for my iPod and I cannot remember the answers to my security questions. What should I do now?

Comment: though the question is different, the answers will eventually actually be the same as this …  [How can I bypass Activation Lock?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock)

Comment: You could try calling AppleCare

Answer (score 1):

I sorry to say this but there is nothing you can do.The only option left for you now is to contact Apple Support team and find out what can be done.I am sure they will assist you further.I hope I answered your question :-)