# Can I find my stolen iPhone if someone reset it and uses different AppleID?

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

I recently bought an iPhone iOS 9.2.1. I am worried, if someone stole it, reset it and uses different AppleID, can I find it?

Comment: It can't be reset if you do not know the AppleID password.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Your question hinged on whether you were successful in applying an activation lock to the device. Does it show up when you log in to https://www.icloud.com/activationlock/ or in your devices when you log in to https://www.icloud.com/#settings? (or is what I wrote above the answer you are seeking?)

Answer (score 6):

Just be sure to switch on Find My iPhone in Settings > iCloud
then not only can it not be reset by anyone without your AppleID & password, but can be

- Pinged to play a sound [if you just lost it in the house],
- remotely put into Lost Mode [which will enable you to put a message on the lock screen, with another phone number to be contacted at, if someone finds it],
- or in extreme circumstances, remotely wiped [though this will itself then disable Find my iPhone].

All this can be done from another iPhone or on the iCloud web site at https://www.icloud.com/#find

See this question & answer to see just how impossible it is for a thief to be able to reset it once you've secured it - [How can I bypass Activation Lock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer I saw many videos in youtube that you can reset an iphone if you forgot a password, thats why i am asking. If he reset it and uses different AppleID can i still find it?

Comment: @ThodwrhsKontoprias See the last paragraph in tetsujin answer for a link to a long discussion on what can and cannot be done to bypass a lock.