# Unable to complete setup of used Ipad

Tags: ipad, mobile-device-management, setup

I recently bought a used ipad air 2 from ebay. But when i tried to do the initial setup i an taken to a configuration page that is essentially a mobile device management setup which essentially says the ipad is remotely configured by someone else. Then when i try to proceed with the configuration its asks for a username and password. which has not been given to me. do u guys know how i can remove this? [image]

I am perfectly fine with jailbreaking the etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I bypass Activation Lock?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock) At least you've got an address to contact... :/

Comment: Activation Lock is not the same as Device Management (which seems to be the issue here).

Comment: but activation lock will be next, once [or if] device management is passed...

Comment: tetsujin, i think you are correct about this being a device management lock. Is there any way to bypass this without the hassle of contacting that bank. The problem is that I'm not from the US and this was bought in America by a friend of mine who was there. so the last thing i want to do is international shipping.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [DEP](http://www.apple.com/business/dep/) enrollment screen. Contact the business that manages that device to either return it to them or have them release the device from management. Only they can release that hardware by Apple policy.

If you don't want to hassle with a potentially stolen iPad, contact eBay to see about a refund or how they handle sales of goods materially different than advertised. *(on the assumption you didn't bid on a locked iPad)*

Comment: It said very clearly that this was an unlocked ipad. I think I will contact that bank to see what is going on. I've already contacted the ebay vendor. I'm waiting for their response. The vendor was a very well established ebay vendor. So i presume they have some reputation to maintain.