# Is there any way to recover your apple ID if you forget both your password and your recovery key?

Tags: apple-id

Is there any way to recover your apple ID if you forget both your password and your recovery key?

If this happens: would it mean you wouldn't be able to use your your iOS devices that used that apple ID with activation lock active?

Could you contact Apple to solve this issue?

I hope it never happens to me, but I'd just like to know this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I bypass Activation Lock?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock)

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me! I created a new Apple ID using my device (because it was the only way to create an Apple ID without having to have a non-iCloud email account associated with it), didn't realise that Find My iPhone was switched on, and then promptly forgot both the password and the security questions/answers for the account. I could still use the device, but I was unable to switch off Find My iPhone or erase the device. So I force-restored the device, but was then presented with the activation lock.

Apple helped me reset the activation lock **because I was able to prove that I purchased the device**. Your receipt contains identifying information such as the Serial Number and IMEI number, so when I provided Apple with this receipt, they were able to remove the activation lock for me.

But I never recovered the Apple ID itself.

Answer (score 0):

Apple covers the options fairly well at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204921

The short answer is it depends.