# iPad Retrieve a passcode to activate IOS 9

Tags: software-update

I need a passcode to activate IOS 9. I don't recall acing a passcode. Is there any way I can retrieve an old passcode or set up a new passcode? It has to be 4 digits. I made 1 wrong attempt and may be shut out

Comment: Either that, or [How can I bypass Activation Lock?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock)

Comment: You generally don't need a passcode for activation. Is this device second hand or possibly stolen? That would explain the details you mention.

Answer (score 0):

The passcode is either an activation locked device or can be restored from iTunes. If you don't need to make a backup or get the data, connect to iTunes and erase and restore.

If you do need the data, be organized trying pass codes until you give up and erase the device.