# I have an iPhone 6 and forgot my passcode!

Tags: password, iphone

I don't have a computer to use to reset it and when I hold the power and home buttons down it restarts and still asks for the passcode.

Will hard resetting my phone solve this? If not, what can I do?

Comment: Couple issues to point out! 1) iPhone model a1549 = iPhone 6, yet tag says iPhone 7. 2) Are you asking how to hard reset the iPhone 6 (or 7?) or how to change your password? 3) Of course you still need your passcode to get into the phone after a restart! What are you talking about here?

Comment: IPhone 6 I forgot my passcode and don't have a computer to do the factory reset. I've tried holding the power and home buttons down together and it just restarts and still asks for passcode. Also I've tried the power and volume down buttons together and it does nothing. How do I hard reset this phone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I bypass Activation Lock?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock)

Answer (score 4):

If you have forgotten your passcode, the only option available to you is to erase your iPhone and start again. Unfortunately, if you haven't got a backup of your data, this will mean you will lose any data you haven't already got saved somewhere. However, on the positive side, any purchases (free and paid) using your Apple ID will still be intact as you can sign in again and redownload them.

While the only option is to erase your iPhone, you do have multiple methods of doing so. I recommend you read [*If you forgot the passcode for your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch, or your device is disabled*](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306).

The above Apple support document will explain your options, including how to restore any data you do have backed up.