# How can you log out of iCloud if you forget the password?

Tags: iphone, icloud, restart

I recently bought an iPhone 6 from a friend, and there's still an iCloud user on the phone. How can I log out of iCloud if I have no clue what the password is? Keep in mind I have no clue what my password is to the email set on the phone either.

Comment: Ask your friend to log out. They should have done this before handing you the phone.

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock

Answer (score 1):

Since you bought it from a friend I would refer them to: [What to do before selling or giving away your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201351) and ask them to take these steps.

You should also familarise yourself with the above info.

In summary though, before selling any iDevice, you should:

- Do a full backup of your device
- Unpair your Apple Watch (if applicable)
- Sign out of iCloud (if applicable)
- Also delete the device from Find My iPhone (if applicable)
- Sign out of iTunes and the App Store
- Do a full Erase of contents and settings

It's fortunate for both you and your friend that you bought your iPhone from a friend.