# Activation lock problem

Tags: ios, icloud, activation-lock

I've recently dug out an old iPhone to sell.

It has activation lock on it which is pretty normal. However, it's linked to an Apple account which has had its password changed since then. I've also removed it from the iCloud interface.

It now refuses to unlock with either my current password or the password I used then... :(

Is there anyway to reset this iphone without having to go through tech support?

Answer (score 4):

Since you removed that device from iCloud list of locked devices, just put the device in recovery mode and restore iOS from iTunes over USB. That wipes everything, including the cached old password.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263

If that fails, post a follow up with the details of the failure like error message.

You could also go through support if needed to prove if you are the original purchaser of the device.

- [How can I bypass Activation Lock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock)