# Can I backup my iphone on Activation lock mode

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, activation-lock

My iPhone 6 is locked to icloud,, it has never been synchronized with iTunes i need a way to backup it,, is there any modded iTunes or any program can help me.

Comment: note: i know the password of my icloud but i need the backup cause i know a way to extract the Apple Id from it..

Comment: If it's activation locked, there's nothing at all you can do with it until you unlock it... using the password you already know.

Comment: i can't unlock it without Apple Id..

Comment: So you don't know your Apple ID but you know the password for it?

Comment: If there was a way round the activation lock, what would be the point of it? @patrix - I'd VTC this as a dupe of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock except I already flagged as unclear.

Comment: @Tetsujin There actually *is* a way to recover a forgotten Apple ID, it's described in the answer to the question I linked to when closing the Q. But I wonder how many people remember the email they registered their AppleID under if they forgot the AppleID itself.

Comment: @patrix - indeed. The 'forgot ID' link is actually linked from the activation lock dupe I proposed, but yours is more direct, sure.