# Reset iCloud password

Tags: icloud, apple-id

How do you reset iCloud password in order to make changes to your account? I am trying to backup my iCloud storage on my iphone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I bypass Activation Lock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock)

Answer (score 1):

Go to [iForgot](https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid) and there you can reset your password using your email or security questions.