# Software Glitch iPad 2 Caused Activation Lock

Tags: ipad, software, unlock

I’m very new to this thread and I hope I’m in the right place for help.

I’ve got an iPad 2 WIFI only model and have an issue, some time ago whilst I was using the iPad it suddenly and out of nowhere went to an activation required screen.

I believe this to be a software issue as the iPad hasn’t gone to the very beginning of the setup process, I’ve attached 3 screenshots showing what it does.

When I turn on the iPad I can see my wallpaper I’m required to enter my PIN to unlock but after that it goes straight to an activation required screen. Unfortunately it’s been years since setting up the device and as I’ve never had need to use iCloud password as I’ve got a seperate iTunes and App Store Apple ID have forgotten it. I can’t reset the password as I’ve got two step verification setup and I can’t find the recovery key, and unfortunately when two step verification is activated Apple automatically take away elements of the account recovery process. I no longer have the option to reset the password by answering security questions, recovery email or even submit an account recovery request.

Unfortunately Apple won’t assist me without proof 
of purchase and as I purchased the iPad in Oct 2013 I’ve found it impossible to get a copy of an invoice from the supplier thus no help at all from Apple.

As the iPad still has everything installed on it is there some way of extracting the password by some means.

Is data extraction or connecting the iPad to my iPhone Wirelessly to access the iPads data even possible?

I’d appreciate any assistance anyone could give me.

[image: iPad Home Screen][image: PIN Lock][image: Activation Lock]

Comment: I’m hoping no one marks this as a duplicate question, it’s a software problem I believe and not a new iOS setup

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t own a MAC/PC and the iPad has never been connected to one as such no backup’s are available. Looks like I’m stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I would try contacting Apple about resetting the password on your Apple ID. Did you set up any security questions? Do you have a recovery email? Your best bet is to give them a call or live chat and tell them that you do not know the password to your account and do not have the 2WA code.

See what they say, you might be lucky enough to get it one-time reset with the right answers to their questions :)

Comment: Unfortunately I’ve got two step verification setup on the account and when this happens all other avenues of account recovery are taken away by Apple and not made available to me.

Comment: Apple doesn’t take away avenues - perhaps ask a second question on why you can’t unlock your account if that’s worth exploring @HamishMcInnes

Answer (score 0):

No. When you are at a passcode lock screen or activation lock screen, you can’t join any new networks.

- [How can I bypass Activation Lock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock)

Bypassing activation lock is close to impossible and usually requires great effort if you cannot prove ownership to Apple’s satisfaction.

What’s the chance you have a computer where it synced or backed up?

Also, check all Apple ID you control in case the device is registered and can be remotely unlocked / released.

Barring that, you might need to sell the device for parts or learn how to repair these / recycle things when you’re done with it.