# Two apple IDs registered on Apple Servers and one local iPad 2 [Reworded]

Tags: ipad, icloud, apple-id

I bought icloud-locked iPad which was stolen from trash center in Denmark. Honestly, I did not know they were stolen and I was scammed. (The seller did not even say they are iCloud locked)

I jailbreaked it and removed Accounts the sqlite database. It did remove locally old apple ID, but not on apple servers. (i have been told, but logically it could not remove it from apple servers)

It then was this login form as if i had logged out normally, I logged in, it was like 2min waiting (seemed a bit too much, like it would not work), but surprisingly it worked and I can see the iPad on my find my ipad page. Localization services are disabled so I cant track its location though.

But since Activation Lock is gained from remote Apple servers (or local account data?) what would happen when i would reset the ipad? I do not want it as i do not want to get activation lock for the old account I do not know the password for.

Comment: Basically, you cannot [Bypass Activation Lock](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/114985/85275) You have stolen goods in your possession, you even know who the owner is. It doesn't belong to you, whether you were scammed or not, it belongs to its original purchaser, who is quite within their rights [in EU if nowhere else] to have it taken from you by the police. You lose, there is no win in this scenario. Caveat Emptor.

Comment: If this was someone else who had **your** machine, would you want them to get access?

Comment: Instead of reposting your question as new, use the edit button on the original to make changes.

Comment: My old one was holded grg

Comment: Tetsujin it's not activation lock I can access the iPad normallt

Comment: Why do my questions keep getting banned when Im asking about apple hardware (it's not like it's other hardware) and ithey literally said reword the question which I did