# Change iPhone 6 Battery with Find My Iphone

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

I have an iPhone 6 with battery issues.  It has find my iPhone enabled but the appleid is locked (it was my girlfriends and she has forgotten everything).

The phone was originally registered to me.  Would it be possible to get the battery changed?  Or is the find my iPhone thing a blocker?

Comment: Your choices would appear to be a dead battery on a locked phone or a new battery on a locked phone… Why not concentrate on the 'locked' aspect? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock