# After updating my iPhone to iOS 13.5.1, I can't login to my Apple ID - "Verification Failed '' error

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-id

I had this problem after updating my IOS device iPhone 6 to 13.5.1 - I have not used this phone for about 4 months and I'm trying to get it working.

Internet is fine but my emails and Google service also stopped working.

I wanted to wipe the device but I can't since I have to turn of the 'Find My iPhone' option which I couldn't since I can't pass the Apple ID verification step.

Comment: Do you mean an iPhone 6S? The iPhone 6 cannot run iOS 13.

Answer (score 1):

I would set aside the phone that’s not working and get control of your AppleID using a web browser on any convenient and secure computer.

- https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage

By design [it is difficult to bypass activation lock](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock) unless you are the original purchaser of the phone and can provide proof of purchase to Apple Support.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201365