# Forgotten Apple ID

Tags: iphone, icloud, email, apple-id, activation-lock

I have an iPhone 6s. The problem is that I've forgotten the Apple ID and I don't have a proof that I own this phone. So I'm trying possible email addresses. So far, I tried nearly 100 email combinations but still I couldn't find it. Is there any program or website to create email combinations?
The email contains my name, surname and a plate number..

Comment: Your question is one that’s basically how to crack a stolen phone. We may close it as off topic as it gets reviewed. Even if it gets closed, read the [help] as an edit to show your exact screen image might help bring it back to topic if it’s narrow enough a question

Comment: 26 letters (then add numbers & special characters) and a non determinate length of username let alone the other parts - even if you could access the fastest computers the time for a solution far exceeds the time you have available.

Comment: But I know the name and surname, and also the plate number I just need a program to create combinations with these informations

Comment: It’s not reasonable to think you once had this exact email and it was working and now forgot that email, but maybe I’m mis-understanding what your situation is. Most people follow bread crumbs in their mail client or work with their mail vendor to retrieve their mail... I’ve taken my -1 vote away since this might be a programming question in the end

Comment: You can't by pass Activation Lock (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock). If you are looking for an easy way to create combinations of name and plate number please rewrite your question accordingly (or just use Numbers/Excel :-)).

Comment: a) What's a "plate number"? b) how many combinations of `johndoe12345` can there be? unless you actually consider anyone would have an email address that's an anagram of that, like `d5jo32nho21e4`. That aside, Apple prompts with `j******5@e***l.com` anyway, so how can't you guess from there?? Second issue - where are you trying to enter this data? A phone won't let you; a few wrong guesses & the timeout will go to days, months, years before you can enter a new guess.

Comment: @Tetsujin I didn’t put this in my question, so you had no way to know I’m trying this as https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid
With this address I can try limitless email.
Plate number is not important it's a number: 81. Shortly, your answer is just to questioning.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to steal a phone. I'm not helping with that endeavour. Once you hack the email address, you're still going to have to be able to receive email at it, because that's where Apple will send the reset request. They're not just going to hand it to you because you managed to guess an email address, you're going to have to prove you have access to that address.

Comment: @SafaTunç I wouldn’t be surprised if Apple has blocked your browser and IP address after failing 100 times at iforgot - you likely are going to get your account further locked by brute forcing this....

Comment: @bmike But apple customer service told me the only way to recover it trying different email combinations.

Comment: Bummer so at least you have that if your address gets locked.

Comment: @bmike Do you know any other way to recover it?

Comment: Just my comment from seven hours ago - work by looking at your email accounts and computers. I still have no clue how you established an AppleID and can’t get back in to it but the system wasn’t designed for that loss of control AFAIK. Didn’t you buy apps or can provide receipts?

Comment: @bmike The phone belongs to my mom, so we all don't know anything about the email address. My brother created her email, but he doesn't remember and says these 3 word must be contain in this email. There is no clue to find this address. The only way that I know is to try.

Comment: I’m sure you will persevere. This is excellent context. Keep at it, slow and steady

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two online tools will help create the possible permutations or combinations you want:

- [Combination Generator](https://textmechanic.com/text-tools/combination-permutation-tools/combination-generator/)
- [Permutation Generator](http://textmechanic.com/text-tools/combination-permutation-tools/permutation-generator/)