# Lost password on iPhone setup

Tags: iphone, password, setup

After an iPhone factory reset, I started with the initial setup where you configure your iPhone.

I have entered a passcode for the iPhone but got to the step where it asks you to restore from an iCloud backup or set up as a new iPhone but I did nothing from there.

Now, I can't remember the password I set up so I cannot complete the setup process.

Is there a way to restart the configuration progress again to set a new password?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It’s not totally clear which pin you seek, but here are the two options:

Yes, if you solely have a pin to unlock issue, that can be remedied in minutes with a restore.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306

No, bypassing activation lock isn’t within scope of this site unless you’re using a MDM.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/clear_the_bypass_code_for_activation_lock
- [How can I bypass Activation Lock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock)