# Forgot old iCloud account password

Tags: icloud, password

I have changed my Apple ID (email and password) on my computer.  However, my iPhone 5 still shows the old email address which is grey so I can't change it. I don't remember the password for that email address so can't log on and can't delete it. How do I recover the password ?

Comment: So you went to Settings, iTunes & AppStore, then your Apple ID is greyed out? Have you tried tapping on it?

Answer (score 1):

If your phone has activation lock, you will have to get control of the old Apple ID to remove the account. The device should keep working, but you won't be able to sign in with the new account until the old is under your control.

You can read the details and what to do with a forgotten password at:

- [iCloud: Find My iPhone Activation Lock in iOS 7](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5818)

If you don't have activation lock, then open the settings app, and tap iCloud

Swipe up so you see the bottom of the screen and press "Delete Account" - answer what you want about any content and you'll know if you need the password when it's ready to remove your old account.

Also, it's not very easy or often even possible to bypass Activation Lock since that would defeat the purpose when someone steals the device.

- [How to bypass iCloud login for iPhone 5 running iOS 7 when email and password was forgotten?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115386/how-to-bypass-icloud-login-for-iphone-5-running-ios-7-when-email-and-password-wa)
- [How secure is Activation Lock on iOS 7 (and later)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104888/how-secure-is-activation-lock-on-ios-7)

If you're not on iOS 7 or later, then please edit that into your question as you might have other options.

Comment: what if i don't have access to the email address anymore?

Comment: @valentina Your best bet is to work with the provider of that email to regain access. Even if it's a work account, you might get them to re-enable it and forward to you the one reset password email you need to receive from that address.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to recover iCloud password. And tricks difer depending on whether you still remember your Apple ID.

**If you still remember Apple ID:**

- Open Apple official site for recover iCloud password with a web browser on your computer.
- Enter the email account you used to sign up Apple ID and click Next.
- Choose Email authentication (you need to check your email) or Answer security questions (enter the right answer as you had provided when you originally create your Apple ID).

Now Apple will provide you a link to reset your password. Just click the link to open the reset password window and enter new a password.

**If you forogt the Apple ID:**

- Open Apple official site for iCloud password recovery on your computer with a web browser.
- Click "Forgot your Apple ID?". In the pop-up window, enter your name and current email address. It's better to enter Prior Email Address too. Click Next.
- Select authentication method: Email authentication or Answer security questions.
- If you've chosen email authentication, check your email to reset a new password. If you've chosen answering security question, then enter the answer exactly as what you set when you originally created your account.