# I forgot a password for iPhone 5C, error 4013 if try to restore

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, restore, unlock

I was not using my iPhone 5C for a long time and forgot a password for it. How to use it now? I left it for some time without a power and the only thing it forgot was time, so now it writes that next attempt to enter a password will be in 49 years from now.

If I try to update my phone, it says

[image]

If I try to restore the phone, the following error occurs:

[image]

Where are these error codes documented?

Comment: Have you tried all the similar answers already given for when people forget their password?  If so, please edit your question to include any error messages you got.

Comment: Did you read the Apple instructions ? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306

Comment: @fsb I didn't found any answers on how to bypass password check

Comment: @Ruskes yes I did; did you ever try them in my situation?

Comment: Also, not to be snarky, but is there a legitimate reason to not contact Apple Support other than a stolen device when you get this error message?

Comment: @bmike opposite question: is there a legitimate reason to hide a way to open owned device other then the fact, that Apple spies it and can control it remotely?

Answer (score 1):

Apple documents iTunes restore error codes online:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201444

So, your next step with that error would be to contact Apple Support.

Comment: I don't want to contact support. If they can do something, then I would like to do it myself.

Comment: Just because you don't want to contact support, doesn't make it the wrong answer. The question here will serve thousands of people over time. That error code is designed to get you to support, @Dims . You'll likely end up finding it's activation locked, and we have duplicate questions and answers on that too. Based on the lack of details, I wasn't going to speculate if you have it iCloud locked.

Comment: Here is two of many answers on bypassing activation locks.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115392/5472 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104888/how-secure-is-activation-lock-on-ios-7 if that's the actual reason for the error code.