# Our iPad is locked and we're not sure of the Apple ID / iCloud password

Tags: ipad, icloud, password, activation-lock

My Granddaughter has lost/forgotten her ID and passwords for her iPad. When the iPad powers on, it goes straight to an iCloud password request and I cannot get past it.

I have installed iTunes on my laptop but it fails to connect to the server (error 310).

I installed iCloud control panel and tried a restore but that failed because of "Find my iPad" was active, which I cannot turn off because of the original password problem!

This is driving me crazy. I just want to reset everything now so that I can hand it back to her. Can anyone help?

Comment: @chris-jones Do you or your granddaughter have any other means to find out the Apple ID (assuming it's not on the screen when you are asked for the password)?

Comment: Hi Patrix, The sign in password request to iCloud shows name1.name2@icloud.com would this be her Apple ID by any chance? (names not shown for obvious reasons).

Comment: @ChrisJones that is likely the user name for the Apple ID, but it doesn't necessarily have to be. AppleID could be any string and mostly people use emails. She could have used name@hotmail.com and been offers the iCloud email for free as part of iCloud.

Comment: Hi bmike, It could be then that we do not have AppleID or passwords. I think she may have only signed up for iCloud by accident, (she is only 11). Children can easily be duped into signing up for things they don't understand. (and adults as well).

Comment: I have found a solution: check my answer on my own question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158663/how-to-know-which-apple-id-is-used-to-lock-ipad-if-the-display-is-dead/158715#158715

Answer (score 3):

If the iPad is a recent gift, Apple offers free support to guide you in reclaiming access to her iCloud account. You can't unlock or restore the iPad with iTunes as the device is truly locked until her password is remembered or reset.

- https://getsupport.apple.com to see if you get free support
- https://AppleID.apple.com to self service reset the password
- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5818 how activation lock works and what to do in your case to recover use of the device

If you don't know how the account was set up, realize that too many wrong guesses will lock that account and make her go through more questions / answers and possibly have to review purchase history with Apple before getting someone to assist in resetting things.

Comment: What if the account username is unknown?

Answer (score 2):

Give the circumstances of your situation, the only option for you is to make an appointment with a Genius at an Apple Store, bringing with you proof of purchase for the device.

The employee will then reset the password and allow you access to the iPad. Only Apple has the power to truly bypass Activation Lock.

There is no way to bypass iCloud Activation Lock outside of Apple. That is why it is such a powerful feature and theft deterrent.

More on Activation Lock: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13695?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Answer (score 1):

**[You can't bypass Activation Lock](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104888/how-secure-is-activation-lock-on-ios-7) without entering your Apple ID.**

You can attempt to reset your Apple ID password at https://appleid.apple.com. You'll be expected to answer a few questions regarding your account.

Comment: I have tried this route but the young lady can not remember the answers she originally gave!