# iPhone 5S stolen, name was changed in Find my iPhone and inforrmation request about factory reset behavior

Tags: security, ios, iphone, find-my-iphone

I got my 5S stolen Thursday and today it was back online in Find My iPhone.

First, I would like to know if there's a way to know if the iPhone is in locked mode or not.

Next, from the time it got back online, the iPhone name has changed. Since my iPhone is password/fingerprint locked, and in locked mode, how can the person who (certainly) bought the stolen phone change the name. He can't go in to Settings, can't access it via iTunes, and even if he restored it he can't activate it because of the iOS7 protection requesting my Apple ID password (am I right on this?). My first answer would be a DFU reset from a previous backup but i would like confirmation about it and other possibilities.

On top of this, when going into locked mode, I'm unable to set a different code than the one already on the device which may be a problemat if the code is the one set by the guy when he did his backup from another iPhone and he re-injected into my phone with a DFU backup reset. How can I set another code to be sure he can't use the phone?

Comment: Activation Lock is generally considered unbreakable at present. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104888/how-secure-is-activation-lock-on-ios-7 although one user here reported that under limited circumstances, they have known Apple to unlock a device for the original purchaser. If the passcode is entered, any thief can change the device or use it. Can you confirm that your iCloud still has control and can lock/erase the device?

Comment: I can still make it ring, lock it, and erase it. So if I understand, it's still locked.

Comment: Given that it's running. Have you called the cop?

Comment: @JimThio Yeah, i've called them, but cops in France are helpless against phone theft. I've been able, with a bit of luck I think, to get the number of the person who bought it to the thief, because I didn't erased it, just locked it with the 4 digits pin code, and she inserted her SIM card into it, sending a "Would you like to add <her phone number> to your iMessage account ?" alert on my Mac. I called her and got it back. BTW I've been lucky. The girl didn't had her money back, and the thief hasn't been found.

Comment: cops are helpless against phone theft?

Comment: @JimThio In France, in Paris and its surrondings, they surely have too many cases but no way to find thiefs. So no, except giving you a paper that you can use if you have any insurance (or if they used your sensitive information, thinking of credit card number/passwords that might be stored in, maybe Apple Pay, etc), you won't get any help...