# How to jailbreak my iPhone 5S with iOS 9.2.1 or iOS 9.3?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, ios, activation-lock

After updating to iOS 9.2.1, I could not enter my iPhone because I forgot my iCloud password (not e-mail) and also my security questions to restore it.

Are there jailbreak options for iOS 9.2.1 and if so, do I need to regain control of iCloud ID to use that option?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. How to jailbreak depends on activation lock being resolved first, so I've edited that out of the question - you can refer to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock for that part of the puzzle. If there's a jailbreak it might or might not need you to regain control of iCloud - but let's see if there are any jailbreak options for iOS 9.2.1 or later...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [iOS 9.1](https://canijailbreak.com/) is the latest jailbreak available. And yes, you would need to [gain access to your Apple ID](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock) in order for the jailbreak to be useful.

Comment: Just curious as to the actual limits of what a Jailbreak can do for a iPhone that's iCloud locked or locked with a forgotten passcode. Is there any Jailbreak known to defeat iCloud lock and/or passcode? And if it could and the iPhone was restored without the Jailbreak would it go back to being iCloud locked?

Comment: @RedEagle2000 So, you're jailbroken. You can run code. But do you, as the user, have the general ability to run that code? No. You're Activation Locked. But, if you took apart the jailbreak, and made a customer version that changed it so that in addition to patching the kernel, you also bypass the Activation Lock code, then you just bypassed the Activation Lock. I don't know of any actual working Activation Lock bypasses. But it's totally possible. Yes, if you restored after doing such a jailbreak, it would go back to being Activation Locked.

Comment: Interesting. Have you ever heard of Jailbreak bypassing Activation Lock? Even for older versions of iOS?

Comment: I have heard of them. But never knew of any that actually worked (they were usually for a specific version of iOS etc) so I was never able to confirm it ever working (company-owned devices that were set up with a personal Apple ID instead of through MDM). Searching now reveals some that claim to work (again, specific versions of iOS) but they're old.

Comment: Here's the deal: it's totally possible. But the people *capable* of doing it are people that have reputations. We could see an overseas version of it happening, but it's not going to be from a reliable/trusted source (again, reputations), so it could contain malware, etc. An Activation Lock bypass is just too political. And the people capable of doing it have nothing to gain from it.

Comment: Good. iCloud Lock shouldn't be able to be bypassed (that's the whole point), but I have always wondered if it was possible by Jailbreak. Thanks for answering my questions.