# What happens if I restore an iPhone with Find my iPhone off?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, apple-id, find-my-iphone

I have an old iPhone of mine and I made its Apple ID on a burner email (I know very stupid of me, I was in middle school then). I recently found it again after like 2 years of it sitting in some box, I want to reset it and sell it but will me not being able to access the Apple ID conflict it if Find my iPhone is off?

Answer (score 2):

If it’s activation locked, restore won’t remove that lock.

If it’s clean, you can restore and it’s ready to use so unless you want to try brute forcing the password, restore it and take your chances.

- [How can I bypass Activation Lock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock)
- [How secure is Activation Lock on iOS 7 (and later)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104888/how-secure-is-activation-lock-on-ios-7-and-later)