# Can I Downgrade my Jailbroken iPhone 4 using iFaith?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

Can I Downgrade my Jailbroken iPhone 4 running IOS 7 using iFaith?

Comment: See my answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114076/18387

Answer (score 1):

If you have iOS 6 SHSH blobs saved, yes. http://www.iphonehacks.com/2013/10/downgrade-ios-7-ios-6-1-3-using-ifaith.html

Comment: I didn't jailbreak iOS 6 so i think i don't have shsh blobs