# iOS jailbreaking before the jump to 7.1

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I have an iPhone 5 - not yet jailbroken - running iOS 7.0.6 (via recent OTA update). I heard about the 7.1 update today and thought if I would ever jailbreak, this would be the time. evasi0n's page states "Over The Air updates of iOS 7 are known to create an issue and make the jailbreak fail." So, I download the appropriate 7.0.6 IPSW and try to restore through iTunes. But it appears Apple has already closed this SHSH blob (today, drats) and iTunes errors out with the "This device isn't eligible for the requested build" error.

I plan on not upgrading to 7.1 until this answer is a definitive "no".

My question: Is there a way for someone in my situation running 7.0.6 (OTA) to Jailbreak?

Comment: The answer is "No." Don't be alarmed, but I'm going to flag this is a duplicate, as it can be answered by my answer to this question here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114076/18387

Comment: Actually, I see that there are two questions here. The first can be answered by that answer that I just linked. The answer to the second question is "try it," because what have you got to lose now that you know the answer to the first question? After you try it, answer your own question here with the results that you discover.