# Restore iOS 6 without going to iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios

I found an old iPhone 4s of one of my family members, it has iOS 6.1.3 installed, but it has a passcode on it, and he does not remember the passcode, and its currently locked, and if I try again I will have to restore. I was wondering if there is a way that I can restore the phone to iOS 6, instead of going to iOS 7? or is there any other ways around this? I really hate iOS 7 on my iPad so I would like to keep the version, while restoring the phone.

- The iphone is in lost mode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Downgrading to a previous iOS version](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102928/downgrading-to-a-previous-ios-version)

Comment: The short answer is *No.* For the long version, see my answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114076/18387