# How to upgrade jailbroken iPhone 4 with iOS 6.1.3 to iOS 7.0.4?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, ios

I bought an iPhone 4 online around a year ago, maybe more, without knowing it was jailbroken (I should have sensed this by the price, indeed too good to be true).

When I tried doing the upgrade everything got wiped out and I had to use RedSnow to restore the newest version at that moment. This was iOS 6.1.3 which was decent — I could use almost everything except making phone calls.

Now a few apps are requiring me to download the newest version of iOS in order to operate properly. The next iOS version that appears suggested is 7.0.4. I have backed up all of my information on both the computer and cloud.

Comment: iOS 7.1 should be the only version that Apple is signing for the iPhone 4, thus, you'll only be able to install iOS 7.1, and there isn't an untethered jailbreak for iOS 7.1 (and the tethered jailbreak is difficult to set up).

Comment: See my answer here for more information: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114076/18387

Comment: You can't update a jailbroken device, restore it, update it, and then jailbreak it again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Restore the device with iTunes (connect the device and click Restore in iTunes).
2. Once the device is restored, set up the device using an iTunes backup and select the iTunes backup that you made before you restored the device.
3. If you want the device jailbroken, jailbreak the device using [evasi0n 7](http://evasi0n.com).

Comment: Thanks! Will this work even if the phone was jailbroken in order to operate? I tried restoring and unblocking through factory but it was not possible. Which means only by using RedSnow I was able to make it work. If I follow the procedure mentioned above will it continue working or will I be facing a blank-unable to use iPhone?

Comment: @Burbi Restoring the device will always return it to factory default regardless of jailbreaking.

Answer (score -1):

Since your iPhone is a jailbroken one, the upgrade needs to happen on the computer connected with iTunes. Firstl of all, backup all the info on the iPhone beforehand. Here are detailed steps:

1. Connect your iOS device to your computer using an USB cable. Wait for iTunes to open and connect to your device.

2.Click on device button to the left of the iTunes Store button in the top right corner in iTunes.

3.Click on the “Check for Update” . If the iOS 7.0.4 update is available it will automatically download and update your device to iOS 7.0.4.

4.You will get a popup message informing you the new update is available. Click on Download and Update button.

5.If you get a popup message informing you that iTunes will update your iPhone to iOS 7.0.4 and will verify with Apple. Click on the Update button.

6.It will then show you the release notes for iOS 7. Click on the Next button. Then click on the Agree button for the terms and conditions.

7.iTunes will now download the firmware file (which can take a long time depending on your internet connection as it can be as big as 2.1GB). After downloading the file, it will process it, extract the software, prepare the device for software update, and install the update.

8.Do not disconnect your device until the update has finished. It can take a few minutes. Your device will be updated to iOS 7.0 and reboot once or twice during the process. You will see while Hello screen after it is successfully update. Follow the on-screen instructions to start using the device.

Comment: This is **very bad advice**. You should never use the Update button with a jailbroken device. This can lead to a best case scenario of losing hundreds of megabytes of space until you restore, to a worst case of the device being stuck in a reboot loop, causing you to have to DFU restore.

Comment: The only way to update a jail broken iPhone is to get the data off of it, then do a full wipe and reinstall. the Jailbreak is designed to prevent the phone from being updated, as doing so will undo the jailbreak, or it will just mess everything up as grgarside has said.