# Update iPad 3 iOS 5.1.1 to 7.0.4 not 7.1?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, ipad

I have iPad 3 iOS 5.1.1 Jailbroken.

I now want to update to 7.0.4 or 7.0.6 but can NOT figure out how. (7.1.1 is currently the official update)

Manual updates thru iTunes to a 7.0.6 restore file always result in "This device isn't eligible" error despite hosts editing. I've tried on multiple computers.

Am I hosed?

Comment: See my answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114076/18387

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't update iOS devices to old versions.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: Actually, you can in certain cases. See my answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114076/18387

Comment: Good info. Thank you for the detailed response. Looks like I'm out of luck for the iPad 3. Guess I'll wait for the iOS 8 jailbreak.