# Installing specific iOS version on iPhone 4S

Tags: ios, iphone, upgrade, versions

I've been asked to purchase an iPhone 4S for a team of developers for testing purposes. Two requirements that have been asked of the iPhone are:

- it should run iOS 7.0 instead of the most recent 7.1 (don't ask me why, I'm oblivious to the reasons).
- jailbreaking is unacceptable

My concern is: if I get an iPhone 4S with an older version of iOS will I be able to upgrade to version 7.0 specifically or will Apple force me to install the most recent 7.1?

Yes, I've seen some similar questions here, on Ask Different, but they were concerned rather with downgrading to a lower version of iOS (e.g. from 7 to 6, etc.) and thus do not seem to apply in my case.

Comment: Without just buying an iPhone that's currently on 7.0, you're most likely going to be out of luck. My answer here describes in detail the requirements of doing what you're asking: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114076/18387 I've been trying to get people to change the title and description of that question to be more generic (I even made my own question, and they closed it on me as a duplicate of the question where my answer currently resides).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer can be pretty short and easy:

I don't see why it should be 7.0 but you can only upgrade to the **newest version** around (this is iOS 7.1.1 as we speak). This is because Apple blocks signing the devices with older firmware files.

Comment: I don't see that either but that's what has been explicitly asked of me and since I'm not an Apple user myself and have no expertise in this field I preferred to ask. This answers my question sufficiently, thank you.

Comment: To extend the answer *slightly*, you can do it, if you have *previously* done it on the *same* device, and had the forethought to save your signed upgrade files.  This doesn't help you, but may help you fend off questions from people who say it *can* be done.  It can, but only in very specific scenarios which do not apply to you.

Comment: Maybe you've already seen this, because I hand out my answer to this like candy around here, but it currently is the only answer anywhere with all of the facts and is kept up-to-date: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114076/18387