# Update iOS 5 to 7.0.6 from copied .ipsw file to phone

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, windows, software-update, error

I've recently downloaded **.ipsw** file (firmware 7.0.6) and want to update my **apple 4s 32 gig** phone (ios 5).
but when I tried to to use iTunes (holding shift key in windows 7 + press update button in iTunes -> choose .ipsw file for update) I got the error below :

[image: error 3194]

http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4451

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?
I've downloded iTunes 11.2 (latest version)

---

**Extra questions:**

I am certainly sure there is no problem about my internet or hosts file.
I turned my anti virus & firewall off and after that still got that error.
Is it possible to transfer .ipsw file to my phone and run it from there?
If yes, where should I copy that file and how can I run it?
If no what is the solution and how can i fix that error?

Comment: Did you try just clicking on the Update button in iTunes and let iTunes download the firmware for you? Apple doesn't sign 7.0.6 anymore. They sign 7.1.1 now.

Comment: so what should i do? there is no untethered jailbreak for 7.1.1 & this is why i want to use 7.0.6.

Comment: Since you don't have blobs saved for 7.0.6, you might be out of luck. Unless someone else has a solution.

Comment: but there should be more luck. if not so sucks...

Comment: See my definitive answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114076/18387