# Can you update an iPhone 4 on iOS 6.1.2 to 7.0.6 using an IPSW file?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, restore

So I have an iPhone 4 that's been happily jailbroken on iOS 6.1.2 for a while now, but I want to upgrade to 7.0.6. I downloaded the IPSW for it and shift-clicked on update, but I get the error 'The iPhone could not be restored. An unknown error occurred (3194)'. I read up on it and proceeded to correct my hosts and firewalls, but nothing seems to work.

So, the question is: Is what I'm trying to do even possible, or should I just settle for iOS 7.1 with no jailbreak? Also, is there any way to update without using iTunes, because it seems to be the only thing causing the problem?

Comment: See my definitive answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114076/18387

Comment: @AndrewLarsson This is asking how to upgrade not downgrade

Comment: @Mark This is exactly why I wish the mods would let me change that question to be more generic. And even when I made my own, they took it down and marked it as a duplicate of that one. My answer stands regardless.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson I would create a question on meta to try to do this then giving your reasons

Comment: @Mark I asked about this before on meta, and it didn't really get anywhere, so I asked a new question about it: http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2153/should-we-make-this-question-about-downgrading-ios-more-generic

Answer (score 1):

iOS 7.0.6 is no longer being code signed by Apple. Only the most recent version of iOS is code signed by Apple, and the iPhone will not accept a version of iOS that has not been code signed. So essentially, this is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Apple is no longer signing iOS 7.0.6, so new installations of that firmware are not allowed anymore. That's why you're experiencing the 319x error.

## Solutions

1. **Stay on 6.1.x**. This is what I would advise - iOS 7.0.x is terribly laggy on the iPhone 4, and iOS 6 is by far the best firmware for iPhone 4 handsets.
2. **Upgrade to 7.1**. iOS 7.1 drastically improves performance, especially on the iPhone 4 and 4s. It is better than 7.0.x, in all ways. You can indeed jailbreak the iPhone 4 on 7.1, using a tool named Pangu. You can also use GeekSn0w for a tethered jailbreak.
3. **Wait for a 'signing fluke'**. Sometimes, Apple randomly starts signing older firmwares for no apparent reasons. I call them 'signing flukes'. For instance, in July 2013, Apple randomly started signing 6.0.x when 6.1.3 was the latest available firmware, allowing users who had updated to 6.1.3 to jailbreak their handsets. If you are especially patient, you could wait for something like this to happen again, but don't hold your breath - they are very rare! You can keep tabs on Apple's signing statuses from [icj.me](http://icj.me/ios/all).

## One more thing...

> I downloaded the IPSW for it and shift-clicked on update

Many people in the jailbreak community advise that you **do not use update functionality of any kind** on jailbroken devices, as anything could happen. Mainly, if you do this, the jailbreak data will clog up your phone, and there will be a large amount of wasted space on your phone, forcing you to restore. So, to save time, restore your phone instead of updating it!

If you want to preserve your data, you *can* back your phone up to iCloud/iTunes and then restore from the backup after restoring your phone. This also leaves traces from your jailbreak, but 'good' traces (like, for instance, if you used TetherMe to enable tethering, it stays enabled when you restore from a backup!)