# I don't want ios 8 on my ipad mini running ios 6. Is there a way that I can update to ios 7?

Tags: ios

I have an iPad Mini running iOS 6.0.1.

I want to install iOS 7 instead of 8.

Is ther a way to do it?

The iTunes update shows update to iOS 8.4.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Downgrading to a previous iOS version](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102928/downgrading-to-a-previous-ios-version)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Apple only allows users to update to the latest software, as it fights version fragmentation. I recommend just updating to iOS 8.4.1. For the most part, whatever bugs existed in iOS 8 are fixed by now. You could also just wait until iOS 9 comes out in a couple of weeks, bug fixes and performance enhancements will be a major part of iOS 9.

This all is an effect of "code signing" where you need Apple to sign the version of code at the moment it gets installed. Since [Apple no longer signs iOS 7 on that device](http://www.macrumors.com/2014/09/26/apple-ceases-signing-ios-7-1-2/), you would need to jailbreak or bypass that entire process.

Unless you're into the details of Jailbreaking you can stay at iOS 6 or upgrade to the versions Apple supports/signs.

I **strongly** recommend **against** jailbreaking, though.