# Can I update to iOS 8.3 using IPSW files?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, ios, ipsw

I recently received an iPhone as a gift. It had not been used in a while, and as such, had been left un-updated on iOS 6.0.1. I am a jailbreak enthusiast, and since there may not be an iOS 8.4.1 - iOS 9 jailbreak, would it be possible to update to iOS 8.3 with its IPSW file (despite it not currently being signed)?

Comment: The answer is simply "No."

Comment: See my answer here for more information: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114076/18387