# Can I downgrade my Ipod4 running IOS 6.1.6 to IOS 5.1.1 then upgrade to 6.0?

Tags: jailbreak, ipod, ios

So I've been wanting to jailbreak for about a good 3 years now (Yes, I am a failure) and have found it near impossible to jailbreak ios 6.1.6 .
Now, I have an iPod4 with ios 5.1.1 (but it is my sisters) and I will be able to create the shsh blobs.

So after admitted defeat of trying to jailbreak ios 6.1.6, I thought of downgrading to ios 5.1.1 and jailbreaking. But this is not a great idea as most of my apps run on IOS 6.

To make a long stoy short, how do I downgrade to ios 5.1.1 then upgrade to **6.0** but not 6.1.6?

Thank you for your time and consideration.

BTW: I don't have SHSH blobs for IOS 6.0
BTW: If you could include a way to get the SHSH blobs off the Ipod4 it would be helpful.

Comment: Im not asking how to jailbreak ios 6.1.6, just incase you are thinking about that.

Comment: You can't. See my answer here for more information: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114076/18387

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Restoring a device to any version of iOS, be it an upgrade, downgrade, or same-version restoration, requires Apple to still be signing it. In some cases, a utility such as TinyUmbrella can trick iTunes into installing an unsigned version, but not only do you need the SHSH blobs to do that (which you don't), no one has figured out a way to get that to work since iOS 5.

So, in short: if you had saved the SHSH blobs when your iPod was running iOS 5, then you could probably downgrade to iOS 5, but installing any version of iOS 6 besides 6.1.6 is impossible at this time.