# Iphone 4S jailbroken stucked in respring logo

Tags: itunes, iphone, jailbreak, java

I wanted to free some space on my Iphone 4S and I deleted the fonts folder from system. When I want to restore .ipsw with the iTunes gave me the error 3194 with internet, and 3004 without internet connection. I edited the host filed and nothing worked. I try to use TinyUmbrella but this doesn't work and said something about Java error like "please define exe4j_java_home 32-bit jdk or jre download". What can I do now?

Comment: Those iTunes errors come from you trying to restore to a version of iOS that Apple is no longer signing. See my answer here for more information: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114076/18387

Answer (score 0):

Put your iPhone in DFU Mode : 
1. Plug your device into your computer with a USB cable.
2. Turn off the device (if it does not turn off the traditional way, hold both power button and home button until it turns off).
3. Hold the Power button for 3 seconds.
4. Hold the Home and Power buttons for 10 seconds.
5. Release the Power button but keep holding the Home button.
6. After about 15 seconds you will be alerted by iTunes saying that it has detected a device in Recovery Mode.
Normally you should be able to install iOS again but there are a lot of chances that you will not be able to back up your data. Moreover, your iPhone will not be jailbroken anymore.