# Is it possible to downgrade iOS 9 to iOS 8 on 4S?

Tags: ios, iphone, downgrade

Accidentally updated to 9 version from 7. It lags a lot so I want to downgrade it at least to 8 version. Is it possible?

Via standart restore feature i get “This device isn’t eligible for the requested build”

Comment: No it's not possible.

Comment: No, it's not possible. See my answer here for more information: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114076/18387

Answer (score 0):

Since the signing window has closed for iOS 8, I don't think there are any ways for you to downgrade to iOS 8. If your device is on iOS 9.1, you're SOL for now.

However, if you're on an earlier iOS 9 build, it is possible to downgrade to iOS 6.1.3 with [Beehind](http://geeksn0w.it/Beehind/) or [Odysseus](http://dayt0n.com/articles/Odysseus/), although you'll need to jailbreak your device in its current state to achieve this.

Comment: So if I understood right for now even if i had jailbroken 9.1 on my 4S I cant use that two methods to downgrade to 6 ?

Comment: @Markelov I meant that in so far as iOS 9.1 currently cannot be jailbroken. I don't see a reason why it couldn't work if it was.